# Incrementing NSArray on button click

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nsarray

I'm reading a text file line by line, and storing it into a NSArray. 
What I want to achieve is to increment the index of my NSArray when the user clicks a button.

Code:

```
 text.editable = NO;
 NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"firstyea" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; // reads file into memory as an NSString
 NSArray *lines = [fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; // each line, adjust character for line endings
 NSString *wat = [lines objectAtIndex:1]; 
 text.text = wat;
 [self.view addSubview:text];
```

So I have to increment `objectAtIndex` by 1 whenever the user clicks a button.
I can do it in C++ by having a variable of type `int`, and saying something like `objectAtIndex:counter++` but I don't know how to do the same thing in IOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with NSArray, you need to use a NSMutableArray
You should take a variable of type `static int`.

For example:

```
static int counter=0; //define it globally

NSMutableArray *tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[tempArray insertObject:@"Your Data From File" atIndex:counter++];
```

Note: Don't forget to release the array after you're finished using it!

Answer (score 0):

Declare an integer i globally. `@property int i`;

in

> viewDidLoad

, declare `i=0`;

```
-(IBAction)BtnClick:(id)sender

{

if ( i < lines.count )

{

   NSString *wat = [lines objectAtIndex:i];

   i=i+1;

}
}
```

Hope this helps.